# Why did my gridview disappear after editing some gridviewroweditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to remove some of my columns in my gridview. Then this method was provided by someone which i tried

```
protected void yourGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[9].Visible = false;
}
```

And

```
GWCase.DataSource = ds;
GWCase.DataBind();

GWCase.Columns[7].Visible = false;
GWCase.Columns[8].Visible = false;
GWCase.Columns[9].Visible = false;
```

The binding of the gridview and the SQL server are done at the page load. This is how my pageload looks like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI";
    conn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT memberreportid, typeofcrime, crdatetime, address, detail, incidentdate, incidenttime, property, victim, suspect from memberreport", conn);
    da.Fill(ds);

    GWCase.DataSource = ds;
    GWCase.DataBind();

    conn.Close();

    ddlpid1.Visible = false;
    ddlpid2.Visible = false;
    ddlpid3.Visible = false;
    ddlpid4.Visible = false;
    ddlpid5.Visible = false;
    ddlpid6.Visible = false;
    ddlpid7.Visible = false;
    ddlpid8.Visible = false;
    ddlpid9.Visible = false;
    ddlpid10.Visible = false;
}
```

There i attempted to change my

```
EventArgs to GridViewRowEventArgs.
```

I ran the code and it didnt work, in fact my gridview disappear. I went to change it back to the original eventargs but the gridview still disappears.

This is the source code of my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GWCase" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" Width="100%" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
</asp:GridView>
```

It seems like by changing the EventArgs causes the whole gridview to fail. I deleted my aspx pages and recreate and copy the same codes and the gridview still disappears.

Comment: you changed the page_load eventargs to GridViewRowEventArgs??

Comment: I was trying out. I changed it, run it, and the gridview disappears. Then i change it back to the `eventargs` and my gridview totally disappears. Even after deleting my previous gridview and adding an empty gridview but still no gridview is being displayed.

Comment: Have you used any try catch block ? One possible  reason why GridView doesn't appears is because the Code terminates before GridView.DataBind().

Comment: I have already tried but it doesn't appear. But i soon works after i went to get my backup copy file. It seems like when i run the as the gridview event argument, all the gridview in my solution disappears.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control over which columns get rendered to the `GridView`, then you can use the `Columns` property of the `GridView`, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GWCase" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" Width="100%" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField datafield="CustomerID" headertext="Customer ID"/>
      <asp:BoundField datafield="CompanyName" headertext="Company Name"/>
      <asp:BoundField datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
      <asp:BoundField datafield="City" headertext="City"/>
      <asp:BoundField datafield="PostalCode" headertext="Postal Code"/>
      <asp:BoundField datafield="Country" headertext="Country"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note: So instead of hiding columns by the `GWCase.Columns[7].Visible = false;` syntax, you just do not define that column to be bound to the `GridView` in the `Columns` section.